# Apple Receipt Validation returning receipts without latest_receipt_info field

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

Clients call my backend code with a receipt they receive from Apple after they start a subscription. After I send the receipt from the server back to apple for validation, it comes back with a latest_receipt_info array.

Just this past weekend (approx. September 14, 2019) I started getting receipts from clients that do not include the latest_receipt_info array. Instead, they just look like the following:

```
   "receipt":{ 
      "receipt_type":"Production",
      "adam_id":1*******1,
      "app_item_id":1*******1,
      "bundle_id":"com.****app.******",
      "application_version":"61",
      "download_id":6********0,
      "version_external_identifier":8*****,
      "receipt_creation_date":"2019-09-12 12:39:48 Etc/GMT",
      "receipt_creation_date_ms":"1568291988000",
      "receipt_creation_date_pst":"2019-09-12 05:39:48 America/Los_Angeles",
      "request_date":"2019-09-16 22:57:56 Etc/GMT",
      "request_date_ms":"1568674676861",
      "request_date_pst":"2019-09-16 15:57:56 America/Los_Angeles",
      "original_purchase_date":"2017-12-27 19:29:40 Etc/GMT",
      "original_purchase_date_ms":"1514402980000",
      "original_purchase_date_pst":"2017-12-27 11:29:40 America/Los_Angeles",
      "original_application_version":"371",
      "in_app":[ 

      ]
   },
   "status":0,
   "environment":"Production"
}
```

This does not appear to be happening all the time, but I have never seen receipts like this before. Why would this start happening now? And does this mean the user should get access to my subscription content or not?

Comment: I think we might get into similar issue in production. Do you see this often after September 2019? It seems like subscription IAPs might be missing from the receipt around the end of September 2019. I'd love to verify that this is happening in the wild with other apps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why you don't get `latest_receipt_info` array is that your clients didn't purchase any subscription. You posted an example of receipt without any in-app purchases being made. You should take a look at iOS code again.